# TTS not working on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, text-to-speech

I m using VS2010. I wrote code that speaks by taking input from text box when I click on button.but the button works fine when I run it on system but not work on IIS. TTS engine is not working on IIS server and I'm not getting any voice.

Comment: Maybe you should show us some code you're using that doesn't work? So we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, your TTS code is running in the code-behind. That code runs on the server, not the client.

It appears to work when you run the site from Visual Studio, but that's only because the server and the client are the same machine in that specific scenario.

When you deploy it to a real server, the code will either fail, or it will make the server speak. Whilst that might be a good trick to scare your IT staff, the user isn't going to hear it.

There is [an unofficial client-side speech API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API), but [browser support is extremely limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=speech). Unless all of your users are using Chrome, Safari or Opera, then it's not going to work.